# Create multirow dataframe from Single row dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is a single row with N columns:

```
   col1    col2    col3    col4   col5    col6   col7     col8    col9      
0  NBA      Mens    Sports  LAL    Lakers   BOS   Celtics    SAS    Spurs
```

Output that I'm looking for is a new dataframe as shown below, Here the first three column value is same for all the rows. However the col4 and col5 values in this new dataframe is replaced by the above DF column values col4,col5 and col6,col 7 and col8,col9 and so on for each row in new dataframe

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   NBA    Mens   Sports    LAL     Lakers
1   NBA    Mens   Sports    BOS     Celtics
2   NBA    Mens   Sports    SAS     Spurs
```

**My Code:**

Convert the single row to ndarray

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('df_info.txt', sep=",", header=0)
vallist=df.as_matrix()[0]
```

Create a Dict to store the values

```
dict={}
n=4
varlist1=[]
for i in range(len(vallist)):
    if(n<=9):
        dict[i]={}
        print(vallist[n],vallist[n+1])
        dict[i]['col1']=vallist[0]
        dict[i]['col2']=vallist[1]
        dict[i]['col3']=vallist[2]
        dict[i]['col4']=vallist[n]
        dict[i]['col5']=vallist[n+1]
        n+=2
```

Import the dict to Dataframe

```
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
df2.transpose()
```

I'm getting the required result but I'm not convinced, looking for more pythonic and panda ways to achieve this.

Comment: Side note: never name a variable after a class, use `d` or `dict_` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a comprehension and clever unpacking.

- for each row I grab the first three values and the rest

  ```
  a, b, c, *x in df.values
  ```
- I then cycle through each pair in the rest by zipping together `x[::2]` and `x[1::2]`
- Use `rename` and `add_prefix` to nail down the column names.
- This generalizes to any number of pairs subsequent to the first three columns.

---

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [a, b, c, d, e]
    for a, b, c, *x in df.values
    for d, e in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])
]).rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1).add_prefix('col')

  col1  col2    col3 col4     col5
0  NBA  Mens  Sports  LAL   Lakers
1  NBA  Mens  Sports  BOS  Celtics
2  NBA  Mens  Sports  SAS    Spurs
```

Comment: oh that's really great and simple solution. Can you upvote the question if you think it will help other users also..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.repeat` and `itertools.chain` with some dictionary comprehensions:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df['abbr_combined'] = list(zip(df.col4, df.col6, df.col8))
df['team_combined'] = list(zip(df.col5, df.col7, df.col9))

lens = df['team_combined'].map(len)

res = pd.DataFrame({**{col: np.repeat(df[col], lens) for col in ('col1', 'col2', 'col3')},
                    **{col: list(chain.from_iterable(df[name])) for col, name in
                            zip(('col4', 'col5'), ('abbr_combined', 'team_combined'))}})

print(res)

  col1  col2    col3 col4     col5
0  NBA  Mens  Sports  LAL   Lakers
0  NBA  Mens  Sports  BOS  Celtics
0  NBA  Mens  Sports  SAS    Spurs
```